# Is there a way to visualize the db schema without a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, schema

Is there a way to visualize the DB Schema in Rails without installing a GEM? Maybe a cpp script that runs against the schema.rb?

Comment: Using a gem like `railroady` or `rails-erd` is the recommended way. If you are trying to understand an existing rails application, it'll be a valuable exercise to create the visual representation of the entity relationships in the application **by hand** :-)

Comment: Thanks... But I specifically asked if there was a way to do it without installing gems.

Comment: What kind of DB are you using?  There are many tools for different db types, have you tried that?  Or do you only want to use a ruby script?

Comment: What's the problem with installing the gems?

Comment: There's no point in avoiding gems. If you are concerned about performance in production,  don't add it to production environment, same with testing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of that would allow you to visualise the associations between models without using gems to reflect on it for you (which is probably what you want to do - since "visualising the schema" doesn't make sense - the schema only has any meaning beyond a list of field names when it's tied to the models describing associations).

Firstly, you can use the "diagram" functionality of an IDE like RubyMine. Or secondly, you can get a pen and paper out, and draw it manually.